# File system error even after using fsck - freezes at "started user manager for UID 1000"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, fsck

(I'm new to linux so forgive me if the terms are wrong or if I'm giving unnecessery details)

I have ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop for several months, in dual boot with Windows 10.

Right now it keeps freezing on boot when it gets to "started user manager for UID 1000". I will try to describe the process that got me there.

Today when I started my laptop I got some error messages on boot and was passed to initramfs prompt. I followed some guides said to use fsck to repair the system. I used it (fsck -f /dev/sda7) and when I rebooted it still showed massage of `contains file system with errors, check force`, did the check and then proceeded with the booting process. "Ubuntu" purple screen showed for a split second and then it got back to boot messages and it kept on a bit and then froze when got to "started user manager for UID 1000", and this process repeats on every boot. When I press the power button this "purple ubuntu loading screen" reappears for several seconds and then the computer shuts down.

I think i should note that there are also more errors on boot massages:
- many ACPI errors
- "problem loading UEFI: db X.509
   couldn't get size 0x0000...00e"
- failed to start load/save RF kill switch status
- failed to activate swap/swapfile

I have tried this thing, following some other related questions here:
1. running fsck and fsck.ext4 from recovery mode's root (no help)
2. editing the grub "quite spalsh" to "nomodeset" (different boot massages but still freeze on the same massage)
3. got to `tty` using ctr+alt+F2 before boot got stuck, but couldn't do much (say, editing the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file as I saw recommended), as file system says its "read only")

Any help would be totally appreciable.

Comment: In Windows, had you installed a driver that allowed you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: No, I was barely using this Windows partition

Comment: Sounds like you have a possible HDD/SSD problem. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start `Disks`. Go to the hamburger icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Look at the data for anything containing "sector"... like relocated or pending or ??. Run the tests. Report back to @heynnema